how to create multiple instances for web server
I'm having a problem, I have a simple website, running on localhost, the requirement is to use virtualization, which means I will have to install a webserver (I use ASP.NET Core so I will probably install IIS), then I will have to instance it into many instances 2, instance 3, ... And there will be one that will coordinate the requests, which means if it checks which server is free, it will throw the request to that server for processing. Can everyone guide me or give me reference sources?
I have searched many references online but there are not many effective. If anyone knows anything, please contribute.

You do not need IIS: use the inbuilt Kestrel. As Kestrel is an executable you can use the command line to pass arguments but better to use a load balancer or reverse proxy (see YARP to build something custom).

You can try reading about web farms too
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/web-farm?view=aspnetcore-8.0

@Richard can you tell me how can i create multiple web server instances? where and how can i create them?

@JerdineSabio That's basically my idea, thanks but I haven't found any specific tutorial yet, I still find it too general

Just like what you can see, Kestrel is used by default if your app is not hosted in IIS. Then if you already published your app, you can run dotnet <yourapp>.dll command to start your application this will make your app run within Kestrel. https://i.sstatic.net/DduPKpL4.png

To run several instances for the same app, you can use dotnet <yourapp>.dll in a CMD window, and run dotnet <yourapp>.dll --urls "http://localhost:5002" in another CMD window.
